# I want to integrate spherical bessel function but it is not coverging

Tags: numerical-integration, special-functions

`L = (1/.197)10;`
`p = Table[i, {i, 1, 50}];`

Roots of spherical bessel function

`ap = Table[N[BesselJZero[3/2, i]], {i, Length[p]}];`

Integration of spherical bessel function

`NP = Table[ Integrate[SphericalBesselJ[1, (ap[[i]] x)/L]^2x^2, {x, 0, L}], {i, Length[p]}];`

Comment: Use `NIntegrate` ?

Comment: OK now it works but why?

Comment: Related [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17634/how-do-you-integrate-a-bessel-function-i-dont-want-to-memorize-answers-or-use) on Math SE regarding integration of Bessel functions. There will be other posts like this for sure. If an expression/integral etc fails to return an analytical solution, a numerical solution is the next thing to try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am using

```
"12.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)"
```

We have:

```
L = (1/.197) 10;
p = Table[i, {i, 1, 50}];
ap = Table[N[BesselJZero[3/2, i]], {i, Length[p]}]
```

First we do the numerical integration

```
NP = Table[
   NIntegrate[
    SphericalBesselJ[1, (ap[[i]] x)/L]^2 x^2, {x, 0, L}], {i, 
    Length[p]}];
```

Now we integrate analytically

```
analytics = 
  Table[Integrate[SphericalBesselJ[1, (ap[[i]] x)/L]^2 x^2, {x, 0, L},
     PrincipalValue -> True], {i, Length[p]}];
```

Finally we compare the results

```
NP - analytics // Chop
```

and we get

> 

```
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0}
```

Comment: I understood. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @AnshulBokade glad I helped